# Date function Typescript

Tags: typescript

How bulid function which will return formatted date

date is in string
in consloe.log I see this: 08.04.2022 16.54

and I want convert this for number / date or formant which I can sort in table :(

I am new to TypeScript :/

```
time = new Date();

  logName(task: Emply) {
    const REGEX_MATCH_DOTS_AND_WHITESPACE = /[\s\.]/ 

      const [day, month, year, hour, minutes] = date.split(REGEX_MATCH_DOTS_AND_WHITESPACE) 
  
  
    return  new Date(year, month, day, hour, minutes);
    
  }


export interface Emply {
  time: string;
}
```

Comment: What's the expected format of the date?

Comment: "I can sort in table" sort how? What kind of table? HTML? Custom component? Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: any format which I can sort  but 'short' will be good

Comment: In my table I had this:  'medium' 8. apr. 2022 16.54.32 and sorting worked by hours not date. So in first I want  change format and I want create fucntion which will convert date. Beacuse if i want sort date I must change this on number etc?

Comment: table sort => Angular material table

Comment: @KrzysztofBojarczuk please edit that information into the question and I will remove the downvote (the system doesn't let me remove it unless the question is edited).

Answer (score 0):

```
let a = new Date().getTime() // or any Date instance
let b = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); // in minutes
let c = new Date(a - b * 60e3); // local time
let d = c.toISOString(); // local "2022-11-25T21:37:14.486Z"
let e = d.replaceAll(/[- ]/g, ' ').replaceAll('T', ' ').slice(0, -5) // whatever you like

console.log(e) // "2022 11 25 21:40:27"
```

Comment: ```export interface TimeClass {

id: number;

  time: string;

}

  getTime(element: TimeClass) {


    let a = new Date().getTime() // or any Date instance

    let b = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); // in minutes

    let c = new Date(a - b * 60e3); // local time

    let d = c.toISOString(); // local "2022-11-25T21:37:14.486Z"

    let e = d.replaceAll(/[- ]/g, ' ').replaceAll('T', ' ').slice(0, -5)
    
    return e;
  
  }```` and how write this fucntion ? :(